# How to get memory usage of 64 bit process from 32 bit process in C#. PerformanceCounter produces wrong result

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter

I'm trying to get memory usage of some 64bit process. 
My code is in test that has to be 32bit (Coded UI test, does not support 64 bit).
Here's code:

```
PerformanceCounter privateBytesCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Private Bytes", proc.ProcessName);
var prvBytesSample = privateBytesCounter.NextSample();
```

result is 4294967295 - which is Max(int32)-1 - it is around 4GB, while process is actually taking up 11.5 GB.
When I put this code in some console app, compiled as 64 bit - it gives out proper result.

Please advise how I can get the proper result from 32bit test.

Comment: Is it possible for you to compile your watchdog app as AnyCPU? It then will automatically start as 64-bit process on a 64-bit system (Don't forget to clear the 'prefer 32-bit' flag).

Comment: `Max(int32) - 1` is `2,147,483,646`

Comment: Decimal `4294967295` is hexadecimal `0xFFFFFFFF`. Interpreted as an `Int32` this 32-bit value would represent `-1`, interpreted as an `UInt32` this 32-bit value would represent `UInt32.Maxvalue`. Neither of which is `Int32.MaxValue - 1`...

Comment: elgonzo, you're right, maybe it's max unsigned int or close to it's max value, Either way - it's incorrect value.

Comment: Dmitry, I can't run this code as 64 bit - since it is coded UI test, which does not support 64 bit.  It is set as "Any Cpu", and runs as 32 bit, When I set tesst to 64bit - test fails to run at all.

Comment: It seems using PerformanceCounters in your situation is a dead-end, as those system-defined memory-related counters in the "Process" category are 32-bit wide for 32-bit processes querying them. I haven't looked much closer, but perhaps you could query [WMI's Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-process) instead of reading performance counters. WMI queries are obviously slower than reading a performance counter, but what can you do...

Comment: elgonzo, I'll definitely look into it.